# How to do HH:mm:ss subtraction in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have below code :

```
moment(moment("23:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss"))).utc().format("HH:mm:ss");
```

produces o/p: 05:00:00 - 
working correctly

```
 moment(moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss"))).utc().format("HH:mm:ss");
```

it produces wrong o.p: 00:00:00:

i need an below o/p: -18:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code looks unnecessarily complex. Let's break it down. First assign the "moments" you want to find the difference to. You don't need `format()` yet. Format returns a string for presentation purposes. You don't need that (yet).

```js
const evening = moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").utc();
const midnight = moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").utc();
```

Diff one moment from the other: the one result will give you a positive result, the other negative. ([it's explained in the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)):

```
const diffFromEvening = evening.diff(midnight, 'hours');
const diffFromMidnight = midnight.diff(evening, 'hours');

console.log('diff from evening', diffFromEvening); // 18
console.log('diff from midnight', diffFromMidnight); // -18
```

Check it live in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/OnerlookedBrilliantFrontend).

Comment: I also don't see the use of `moment.utc()` in this case, so it can even be further simplified by omitting that.